# asyncImageView crashing while loading images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asyncimageview

Facing crash issue while loading set of images with urls with **asyncImageView**. The error I am getting is `-[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
  #define IMAGE_VIEW_TAG 99
  if (cell==nil)
  {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 44.0f, 44.0f)];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    imageView.tag = IMAGE_VIEW_TAG;
    [cell addSubview:imageView];
  }
  cell.textLabel.text = [arrTweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
  NSString *urlString=[arrProfilePics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

  AsyncImageView *imageView = (AsyncImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_TAG];

  [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:imageView];
  imageView.imageURL = [arrProfilePics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: are you sure that arrProfilePics is not nil?

Comment: i checked that , pics urls array is not null and all are valid urls

Comment: imageView.imageURL want a NSString or NSURL? because you doing NSString *urlString = [arrProfilePics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and after imageView.imageURL = [arrProfilePics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ... maybe should be imageView.imageURL = url; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using NSString as NSURL.

Comment: wlcm cracker...Happy Coding!!